# Error for a given function: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Tags: python, typeerror, vectorization, equation

i am a newbie and currently trying to plot this function so I can choose a range of x values for which I should perform my experiments in the ChemistryLab.

I found different articles on plotting functions and it all worked with generic functions like sin(x).
But once I input my function it does not work. The problem already occurs after the first two lines:

```
import numpy as np
import math

X = np.linspace(0, 512, 256)
f = ((x+22)- math.sqrt((x+22)**2-4*2*x))

--> TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

I found threads saying X should be vectorize, however I could not come up with a solution.

Thanks for help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Create a vectorized function. For example:

```
    equation_func = np.vectorize(math.sqrt)
    new_f = equation_func(X)
```

Swap math.sqrt with a function containing your more sophisticated equation and you're home.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to implement a mathematical function in Python is, perhaps unsurprisingly, as a Python function. Then you can, for example, use that function in a list comprehension to get an array of values:

```py
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = np.linspace(0, 512, 256)

def f(x):
    return x + 22 - math.sqrt((x + 22)**2 - 8 * x)

Y = np.array([f(x) for x in X])

plt.plot(X, Y);
```

[image: function plot]

Comment: Thank your for quickly replying and the elegant solution!